# Print lower triangular packed matrix in Fortran 77

Tags: matrix, printing, fortran, fortran77, triangular

I have a matrix of real*8 numbers saved in an array as a packed lower triangular matrix:

```
|1  *   *   *   *   *|
|2  7   *   *   *   *| 
|3  8  12   *   *   *|
|4  9  13  16   *   *| => [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9...21]
|5 10  14  17  19   *|
|6 11  15  18  20  21|
```

I want to be able to print it in the following format:

```
 [row|col]   1  2   3   4   5   
     1       1  *   *   *   *   
     2       2  7   *   *   *   
     3       3  8  12   *   *   
     4       4  9  13  16   *   
     5       5  10 14  17  19   
     6       6  11 15  18  20  

 [row|col]   6  
     1       *  
     2       *  
     3       * 
     4       *  
     5       *   
     6       6
```

The problem I have is that I don't know how to loop into the matrix elements without the need to creating extra arrays to save the elements by columns and then print them. this is what I have tried so far

```
      Implicit Real*8 (A-H,O-Z)


      INTEGER      ARRAY(21)



      10 Format(5X,'[Row|Col]',5(8X,I6))
      Icol=6
      Num1=1
C     Test array
      DO  K=1,21
      Array(K)=K*1.0d0
      ENDO

C     Print the elements row-by-row.      
44    Num2=Icol-Num1 
      Num=Num2  
      If ((Num2).gt.5) Num=5 
      Write(*,10) (I,I=Num1,Num1+Num)
      INum1=INum1+Num
      if (Inum1.ne.Icol) goto 44       
      STOP 
      END
```

Comment: Is the 6th column supposed to be separated from the first 5?

Comment: Yes, I want to print 5 columns at the time so they can fit without a problem in my output.

Comment: Please use [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions to get more attention. Also use some indentetion in yur code to make it readable and consider using some less pre-historic version of Fortran in year 2017. Not the code yu show has syntax errors like `ENDO`. You should show the **real code** [mcve].

Comment: Start by developing a formula to calculate the index in the array of the value to print at a given coordinate in the matrix.

Comment: I doubt you actually need fortran 77, more likely you are just using fixed format input. The answer (which looks fine to me) is *not* fortran 77.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to identify the formula designating the non-zero elements of the lower triangular matrix. If i and j are running indices for rows and columns respectively, then (j < i) elements will be in the lower triangular part. Here is the code:

```
PROGRAM print_low_tri_matrix
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER :: i,j,n,m,p
REAL ,ALLOCATABLE, DIMENSION(:,:) :: a
REAL, ALLOCATABLE, DIMENSION(:) :: r

n = 6
p = n*(n+1)/2   ! Number of non-zero elements in a lower triangular matrix of size n by n

ALLOCATE(a(n,n),r(p))

DO i = 1, p
        r(i) = i*1.0    ! Array containing the non-zero elements
END DO

m = 1          ! Index tracking the non-zero elements array r 
DO j = 1,n
        DO i = 1,n
                IF(j .LE. i) THEN       ! Non-zero indices of the matrix
                        a(i,j) = r(m)
                        m = m + 1
                ELSE
                        a(i,j) = 0.
                END IF
        END DO 
END DO


!       Printing the full matrix a - uncomment for checking 
!         DO i = 1,n
!                         WRITE(*,*) (a(i,j),j=1,n)
!         END DO


!       Printing the matrix a as needed
DO i = 1,n
        DO j = 1,n
                IF(j .LE. i) THEN
                        WRITE(*,'(F12.4)',ADVANCE="NO") a(i,j)
                ELSE
                        WRITE(*,'(A12)',ADVANCE="NO") '*'
                END IF

                IF (j .EQ. n ) WRITE(*,*) 
        END DO
END DO

END PROGRAM print_low_tri_matrix
```

And the output will be:

```
1.0000           *           *           *           *           *
2.0000      7.0000           *           *           *           *
3.0000      8.0000     12.0000           *           *           *
4.0000      9.0000     13.0000     16.0000           *           *
5.0000     10.0000     14.0000     17.0000     19.0000           *
6.0000     11.0000     15.0000     18.0000     20.0000     21.0000
```

Of course, you can change the matrix into an integer array if you wanted.

P.S :- To make this work in f77, you can change the format specifiers as  `WRITE(*,'(F12.4)',ADVANCE="NO") a(i,j)` to `WRITE(*,'(F12.4,$)') a(i,j)`. The allocations of the arrays should be removed and defined directly.

Comment: The OP has asked for fortran 77, which I doubt they actually need. But it might be worth noting that your code is not F77 compliant.

Comment: @Ross, Yes, you are right. I forgot to make it f77 standard. But I hope the OP can modify this appropriately. I will add a note in the answer.

Comment: One needs to do a lot more than change the `write` statement and dynamic allocation to make this (needlessly) F77-compatible.  And note that `$` editing isn't F77 anyway.